# How can I split api-stub/routes.js in ember app kit

Tags: ember.js

I need some advice on how to split
api-stub/routes.js into api-stub/routes1.js, routes2.js,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can do this by adding the new files in express-server.js

```
if (proxyMethod === 'stub') {
  grunt.log.writeln('Using API Stub');

  // Load API stub routes
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  require('../api-stub/sales/sales.js')(app);
  require('../api-stub/contact/contact.js')(app);
```